# Supposedly hard combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

> Your friend John's birthday party is in a week, and you have \$10 to buy him a gift. You decide to get him as many things as you can from the convenience store. The convenience store sells:
>
> - Three different kinds of hoodies that cost \$6, \$7, and \$8 respectively
> - Five different T-shirts that cost \$5, \$6, \$7, \$8 and \$9 respectively
> - Toys: stuffed rabbit for \$5 and a teddy bear for \$4
> - Books: on sale for \$1 each
> - Chips: Fritos cost \$3 a bag and Walkers cost \$2 a bag
> - Candies: \$1 per bar and \$3 per bag
> - Music: CDs cost \$2 and vinyls cost \$4 dollars

John also does not want multiple gifts of the same category (he does not want two hoodies, or a CD and a vinyl). How many ways can you buy things for John such that you use up all of your money?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** This is the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in
$$(1+x^6+x^7+x^8)(1+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9)(1+x^4+x^5)(1+x)(1+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^3)(1+x^2+x^4)$$
The answer is:

> $\large{65}$

Comment: @T.Ou Each possible choice of items totalling $k$ dollars can be found by choosing the associated terms within the brackets of the above and multiplying them together. This process adds one to the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of the above product. For example, choosing a $6$ dollar hoodie and a $4$ dollar teddy bear is given by multiplying $x^6$ in the first bracket with $x^4$ in the third bracket and $1$ from every other bracket thus the result is $x^{10}$.

Comment: @T.Ou The total number of ways to select monomials that multiply to get $x^k$ in the resulting product is the same as the coefficient of $x^k$. Thus the coefficient of $x^{10}$ equals the total number of possible choices.

Comment: @T.Ou you should accept this answer and not delete your question.